# What is the essence of Steve Jobs' quote in the given article, what exactly does he want to convey?

Tags: meaning, comprehension

Jobs had another great quote about saying no: “I’m actually as proud of the things we haven’t done as the things I have done. Innovation is saying no to 1,000 things.”

It is in the superscript 6

Article link:- https://jamesclear.com/saying-no

Comment: An important part of the art of choosing the right things to do is recognising, and rejecting, the wrong things to do.

Comment: What is he proud of ? And what does he mean by things "we" haven't done ....things "I" have done , why has he used we and I here

Comment: You know who Steve Jobs was, right?  He was the founder of Apple. 
 He's probably using *we* because he's talking about the entire company, not just himself personally.  He was proud of both the things that Apple did and the things that Apple did not do.

Comment: Also, you should say "in *footnote* 6".  *Superscript* just means "a letter or number written smaller and higher".

Comment: @stangdon he used "we" for company , then why did he choose "I" then to point him out persoanlly ?

Comment: @stangdon yeah sorry I was a bit skeptical of what word to use there, as I felt like foot notes are present at the very end of page, my bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misquotation; the original quotation was from a [2008 interview with Fortune magazine](https://archive.fortune.com/galleries/2008/fortune/0803/gallery.jobsqna.fortune/6.html):

> I'm actually as proud of many of the things we haven't done as the things we have done.

Note that in the original he doesn't use "we" and then "I", but stays consistent with "we". The context makes it clear that the "we" in question refers to his company, Apple - he is just as proud of the things Apple avoided doing as the things that it did do. He gives an example:

> The clearest example was when we were pressured for years to do a PDA, and I realized one day that 90% of the people who use a PDA only take information out of it on the road. They don't put information into it. Pretty soon cellphones are going to do that, so the PDA market's going to get reduced to a fraction of its current size, and it won't really be sustainable. So we decided not to get into it. If we had gotten into it, we wouldn't have had the resources to do the iPod. We probably wouldn't have seen it coming.

He is saying that his company only had a limited number of resources, so if they had spent time, effort and money trying to do too many different things, they wouldn't have been able to focus on the important things. He is proud they were able to successfully identify which areas not to focus on, so they could focus on the right areas.

Comment: Thank you so much :) great explanation :D